# Scala map list based on list element index

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a created a list of strings in Scala that represent column names in a table:

```
val cols = List("Col1","Col2","Col3")
```

Which I would like to transform to the following string

```
(select Col1 as value,sum(1) as count from sometable group by Col1) a
union (select Col2 as value,sum(1) as count from sometable group by Col2)
union (select Col3 as value,sum(1) as count from sometable group by Col3)
```

The intention is to execute this string through Spark SQL to create a new dataframe with a summary of all the columns listed in the cols list (the actual SQL code contains more than just the sum(1) component but is not relevant to the question).

I am brand new to Scala and programming in general, and found this tricky mostly due to the required "a" (or whatever alias you choose) before the first "union" in the transformed string.

So I came up with the following solution (don't judge), is there perhaps any better way of doing this?

```
def mapWithIndex (s : String, i : Int) {

var outputString = ""
if (i == 0) {outputString="(Select "+s+" as value, sum(1) as freq from sometable group by "+s+") a"}
else {outputString="(Select "+s+" as value, sum(1) as freq from sometable group by "+s+")"}
return outputString
}

val transformedString = cols.zipWithIndex.map(case (s,i) => mapWithIndex(s,i)).mkString(" union ")
```

There might be some small errors in the code since I had to retype everything (I can't copy off the server on which I am working), but I'm sure you get the gist of it.
Although this works fine it feels like I'm being inefficient for the following reasons (and probably a whole lot more):

1. It looks like it must be possible to put the required logic into the anonymous(?) function within the map() statement. I couldn't find a way of accessing the List item index which would show whether or not the darn "a" should be included in the string.
2. The mapWithIndex function contains a var and not a val which from what I have read I should try to avoid
3. It feels like the mapWithIndex function shouldn't have to repeat the whole select statement within each condition, but rather only append the "a" if i == 0. I can't get the syntax right.

Many thanks for reading my question, and thanks in advance for any help you might be able to give.

Comment: nyavro's answer looks good. I would like to point out that in scala `if` is an expression, hence it is evaluated and returns a value so your `mapWithIndex` function should just skip the `outputString` variable entirely and have a body of `if (i == 0) "your first string" else "your second string`. To avoid typing in the same thing twice you could do what nyavro suggested, he just did it in anonymous function.

Comment: Got it thanks Lukasz!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val transformedString = cols
  .zipWithIndex
  .map {
    case (name, index) => s"(select $name as value,sum(1) as count from sometable group by $name)" + (if (index==0) " a" else "")
  }
  .mkString(" union ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```scala
val selects = cols.map(c => s"(select $c as value,sum(1) as count from sometable group by $c)")
val transformedString = selects.head + selects.tail.mkString(" a union "," union ","")
```

Comment: Like this the first two queries aren't joined with `union`.